# Using idxmax and idxmin to change values in different rows

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-loc

I am trying find the cleanest, most pandastic way to create a new column that has the minimum values from one column in the same row as the maximum values in another column. The rest of the values can be nan as I will be interpolating.

```
rng = pd.date_range(start=datetime.date(2020,8,1), end=datetime.date(2020,8,3), freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(rng, columns=['date'])
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.drop(['date'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df['val0']=np.random.randint(0,50,49)
df['val1']=np.random.randint(0,50,49)
```

One realization of df (cut and paste for reproducability):

```
                     val0  val1
date                           
2020-08-01 00:00:00    17     4
2020-08-01 01:00:00    89     0
2020-08-01 02:00:00    85    48
2020-08-01 03:00:00    83    13
2020-08-01 04:00:00    56    65
2020-08-01 05:00:00    48    31
2020-08-01 06:00:00    55    11
2020-08-01 07:00:00    15    87
2020-08-01 08:00:00    92    70
2020-08-01 09:00:00    95    57
2020-08-01 10:00:00    68    79
2020-08-01 11:00:00    87     7
2020-08-01 12:00:00    43    15
2020-08-01 13:00:00    23     4
2020-08-01 14:00:00    68    13
2020-08-01 15:00:00    68    63
2020-08-01 16:00:00    28    86
2020-08-01 17:00:00    12    40
2020-08-01 18:00:00    51    20
2020-08-01 19:00:00    20    48
2020-08-01 20:00:00    79    78
2020-08-01 21:00:00    67    89
2020-08-01 22:00:00    46    52
2020-08-01 23:00:00     7    47
2020-08-02 00:00:00    14    73
2020-08-02 01:00:00    70    30
2020-08-02 02:00:00     2    39
2020-08-02 03:00:00    65    81
2020-08-02 04:00:00    65     8
2020-08-02 05:00:00    83    60
2020-08-02 06:00:00     1    64
2020-08-02 07:00:00    13    63
2020-08-02 08:00:00    45    78
2020-08-02 09:00:00    83     7
2020-08-02 10:00:00    75     0
2020-08-02 11:00:00    52     3
2020-08-02 12:00:00    59    34
2020-08-02 13:00:00    54    57
2020-08-02 14:00:00    90    66
2020-08-02 15:00:00    82    56
2020-08-02 16:00:00     9     2
2020-08-02 17:00:00     5    51
2020-08-02 18:00:00    67    96
2020-08-02 19:00:00    18    77
2020-08-02 20:00:00    28    89
2020-08-02 21:00:00    96    53
2020-08-02 22:00:00    28    46
2020-08-02 23:00:00    41    87
2020-08-03 00:00:00    26    47
```

Now I find idxmax for and idxmin:

```
minidx=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).idxmin()
maxidx=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).idxmax()
```

minidx:

```
                          val0                val1
date                                              
2020-08-01 2020-08-01 23:00:00 2020-08-01 01:00:00
2020-08-02 2020-08-02 06:00:00 2020-08-02 10:00:00
2020-08-03 2020-08-03 00:00:00 2020-08-03 00:00:00
```

maxidx:

```
                          val0                val1
date                                              
2020-08-01 2020-08-01 09:00:00 2020-08-01 21:00:00
2020-08-02 2020-08-02 21:00:00 2020-08-02 18:00:00
2020-08-03 2020-08-03 00:00:00 2020-08-03 00:00:00
```

In this case, I would like to put the minimum daily value (7) located at 2020-08-01 23:00:00 into a new column at 2020-08-01 21:00:00 (i.e. adjacent to 89, the daily max of val1), and do the same for all other dates so the 'new' value on 2020-08-02 18:00:00 will be 1 (i.e. the minimum daily value occurring on 2020-08-02 06:00:00).

I tried the following, but I just get a bunch of nans:

```
df.loc[maxidx['val1'].values,'new']=df.loc[minidx['val0'].values,'val0']
```

If I just set it to an int (`df.loc[maxidx['val1'].values,'new']=6`), I get the int in the places I want the new values. The values I want are give by `df.loc[minidx['val0'].values,'val0']`, but I can't seem to get them into the dataframe.

`minidx['val0'].values` and `maxidx['val1'].values` are arrays of the same size with elements of type numpy.datetime64, and they are all generated from the same dataframe so maxidx and minidx should exist in df.index (`df.index.values`).

Is there an obvious reason this isn't working? Thanks

Comment: IIUC you could have used `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="D")).agg({"val0":"min", "val1":"max"})` directly?

Comment: From what I am seeing, that gives me the values, but not the indices. What I need are the indices so I can assign the value of "new" to the proper row (i.e. the "date_time" of maximum val1).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I have found is to loop through the idxmin and idxmax:

```
for v0,v1 in zip(minidx['val0'].values,maxidx['val1'].values):
    df.loc[v1,'new']=df.loc[v0,'val0']
```

This gives me what I want, but doesn't seem very pandastic, so any other suggestions to accomplish the same thing would be great.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do this using [NamedAgg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html?highlight=filter#named-aggregation):

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).agg(val0_min_time=('val0','idxmin'),
                                     val0_min_value=('val0','min'),
                                     val0_max_time=('val0','idxmax'),
                                     val0_max_value=('val0','max'),
                                     val1_min_time=('val1','idxmin'),
                                     val1_min_value=('val1','min'),
                                     val1_max_time=('val1','idxmax'),
                                     val1_max_value=('val1','max'),)
```

Output:

```
                 val0_min_time  val0_min_value       val0_max_time  val0_max_value       val1_min_time  val1_min_value       val1_max_time  val1_max_value
date                                                                                                                                                      
2020-08-01 2020-08-01 23:00:00               7 2020-08-01 09:00:00              95 2020-08-01 01:00:00               0 2020-08-01 21:00:00              89
2020-08-02 2020-08-02 06:00:00               1 2020-08-02 21:00:00              96 2020-08-02 10:00:00               0 2020-08-02 18:00:00              96
2020-08-03 2020-08-03 00:00:00              26 2020-08-03 00:00:00              26 2020-08-03 00:00:00              47 2020-08-03 00:00:00              47
```